# assigning constant in a ruby module

Tags: ruby

I have a module:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    TEST = "ok"

    def self.is_ok; true end
  end
end

Foo::Bar::TEST # => "ok"
Foo::Bar.is_ok # => true
```

I would like to have another constant inside the module that is defined, just once.

I tried like this:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    TEST = is_ok

    def self.is_ok; true end
  end
end
```

I then get an error saying `undefined local variable or method 'is_ok' for Foo::Bar:Module`. This means that `is_ok` is not yet defined.

Are constants defined at some other point in time than module class methods?

Furthermore, I have another example:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    TEST = "ok"

    def self.is_ok; true end
  end

  module YYY
    TEST = Foo::Bar::TEST
    TEST2 = Foo::Bar.is_ok
  end
end
```

Here, I get:

```
Foo::Bar::TEST2 # => true
```

as expected.

Comment: "Are constants being defined at some other point in time than module class methods?" – Hint #1: at what point is `TEST_OK` defined? Hint #2: at what point is `is_ok` defined? Hint #3: which point comes first?

Comment: question was already answered, and your comment is not helpful 
HINT #4 sarcastic hints are not helpful and discourage people from asking questions

Comment: This question looks like it comes from someone who is learning Ruby. Guiding someone to the solution is generally preferred to just handing them the solution, since it re-inforces learning. At least, that's what it's like for me. Using the hints I gave, might guide the learner into the right direction, such that she might discover the answer herself, which will be a much more gratifying and useful learning experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply a matter of definition order:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    def self.is_ok
      true
    end
    TEST = is_ok
  end
end
```

works exactly as you'd expect.

The simple reason is that Ruby class definitions are evaluated line-by-line; at the time that `TEST` is assigned in your example, `::is_ok` isn't defined yet!

Comment: ha! that's so simple, yet it didn't cross my mind, thanks! :)